# How to mass print in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a grid on a map of my city. I have 1500 plant species in a CSV and need to print each species on a copy of the map in the grid. So I will have 1500 PDFs of the same map but with a different point layer representing which grid squares contain each species.

Is there a way to automate this somewhat so I don't have to create 1500 different print layouts? I can have each species as a layer or names as attributes in 1 layer, there are only:X,Y coords, species name data and red list status as data.

Comment: Did u check **QGIS Atlas** functionalities ? I guess this should fit your needs ... the 'cover layer' of the atlas being your species point layer ...

Comment: apply a rule-based style to the point layer, with a rule that filters it to just the current atlas species, eg `"species_name" = @atlas_pagename`